# vscode terminal showing '>>>' after running a file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

after I run a python file in vscode, the command line in the terminal restart as `>>>` instead of `wwti@I-Air \~ %`, and therefore I can't run the command in the terminal directly like code. or cd. And these lines always show up when I first run a python file with a new terminal. How can I fix it? Thanks!

```
/usr/bin/python3
wwti@I-Air ~ % /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022, 12:41:40) 
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("Hi")
Hi
>>>
```

I have tried to use different python interpreter and still show the same lines with that interpreter version.

I just installed the vscode and python by following the instruction from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial. I used `brew install python3` to install python. `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` has been selected in the Command Palette.

Comment: That's just the prompt of the Python REPL. It's normal and expected. If you want to use shell commands, you have to exit the Python interpreter again (or use a different terminal tab in VS Code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the normal output, it means you are currently using the python interpreter.

To exit the python interpreter, you can type `exit()` directly on the command line or press `ctrl Z + enter`.